# Firebird using non-optimal plan for INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-execution-plan

I have a master table A, and a child table B. Every record on A can have 0..N child records in B (like an order -> items relationship).

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE TIMESTAMP,
    OTHERFIELD CHAR(1),

    CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
CREATE INDEX IX_A_DATE ON A (ORDER_DATE);

CREATE TABLE B (
    ORDER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ITEM_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ITEM_VALUE NUMERIC(15,2),

    CONSTRAINT PK_B PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID, ITEM_NO),
    CONSTRAINT FK_B_A FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES A (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I then inserted some random data on the tables (about 40k records in A and 80k records in B), resulting in statistics `0.000024` for `PK_A` and `0.000672` for `IX_A_DATE`. OTHERFIELD is filled with '0' (30k records) or '1' (10k records).

Now, when I run this query:

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(b.ITEM_VALUE) FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON b.ORDER_ID = a.ID
WHERE (a.ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31')
    AND (a.OTHERFIELD = '0')
GROUP BY a.ID
```

I get this plan: `PLAN JOIN (A ORDER PK_A INDEX (IX_A_DATE), B INDEX (FK_B_A))`, which runs very fast.

If I remove the second where condition (OTHERFIELD = '0'), however, the server chooses this plan: `PLAN SORT (JOIN (B NATURAL, A INDEX (PK_A)))`, which is very unoptimal and slow.

PS: I'm using `INNER JOIN` because only non-empty orders should be listed. `LEFT JOIN` has no problems, and I can filter non-empty orders then. But `INNER JOIN` is preferrable, since it can use indexes from any of the two tables to optimize the query, depending on the `WHERE` conditions.

Anyone has any idea why is this second condition helping optimization choose the best plan? I thought only the ORDER_DATE condition should be enough, since this fields is indexed.

Comment: Which Firebird version?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry about the long delay. It's WI-V2.5.2.26540. But it turned out to be just statistics problem unupdated on the B table indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, your problem was related to out-of-date statistics on indexes of the table. That problem can be solved by recalculating statistics using the [`SET STATISTICS`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-idx.html#fblangref25-ddl-idx-setsttstcs) statement of Firebird.

For example, to recalculate the index statistics of the primary and foreign key of table B:

```sql
set statistics index PK_B;
set statistics index FK_B_A;
```